# How to copy an old revision from another subversion branch to the head revision on trunk?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I have a repository where I have branched and merged back in some changes in to trunk. However I need to now revert trunk back to a revision on my branch.

I imagine the solution is to use svn merge however I have not succesfully been able to use this accross branches.

Any suggestions would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the old trunk away

```
svn move http:///.../trunk  http://..../branches/abandoned_trunk
```

And then copy the old revision to become the new trunk

```
svn copy http:///.../branches/the_branch@1234 http://.../trunk
```

Comment: Would this remove the past revisions on trunk? I could do with keeping these on trunk if possible

Comment: Nothing ever is removed in subversion. You can still see them by looking at /branches/abandoned_trunk. If you start from the new trunk, it will of course show you the history of the former branch (up to the revision when it was copied).

Comment: If you want to have a version history that has everything from the current trunk, and then a single change that puts it to the state of the other branch, you will have to merge instead.

Comment: Hmm, think I'll try the way you originally suggested. Thanks

Comment: If you do not like it, you can move things back again ;-)